What is the relationship between $ \hat{Q} |\psi⟩= q |\psi⟩$ and the collapse of the wave function?
I apologise in advance if this question seems ignorant
Before measurement, a particle can exist in multiple states simultaneously. However, when an observation is made, the wave function "collapses" to a specific state, reflecting the outcome of the measurement.
The action of the operator $\hat{Q}$ on a wavefunction is defined as
$$
\hat{Q} |\psi\rangle= q |\psi\rangle
$$
After the measurement operator has been applied, the value $q$ has been extracted from the system, but the wave function is identical before and after measurement? I do not see where the wave function has "collapsed"?

"Defined", so you consider $|\psi\rangle$ an eigenstate of $\hat Q$, already.

$\hat{Q}$ is an operator that corresponds to an arbitrary physical observable. Applying an operator to a quantum state does not correspond directly to taking a measurement of that state.
What you have defined is the action of $\hat{Q}$, not on a general state, but on one of its eigenstates. If $\hat{Q}$ is defined on an $N$-dimensional Hilbert space, and $|\psi_1\rangle…|\psi_N\rangle$ are the normalized eigenstates of $\hat{Q}$ with eigenvalues $q_1,…,q_N$, then for a general state $|\phi\rangle=a_1|\psi_1\rangle+…+a_N|\psi_N\rangle $,
$$\hat{Q}|\phi\rangle=q_1a_1|\psi_1\rangle+…+q_Na_N|\psi_N\rangle$$
When you measure the value of $Q$, you will measure some value of $q_i$ with probability $|a_i|^2$, and the state collapses to $|\psi_i\rangle$.
EDIT: Perhaps I should clarify that, in general, things may be slightly more complicated. An operator $\hat{Q}$ may have an associated degeneracy, meaning that there exist orthonormal eigenstates $|\lambda_1\rangle...|\lambda_M\rangle$ which all share the same eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Say we have a state $|\phi\rangle$ composed of two such degenerate states, plus some other stuff ($|\psi\rangle$): $|\phi\rangle=a_1|\lambda_1\rangle+a_2|\lambda_2\rangle+|\psi\rangle$. We take a measurement and measure $\lambda$. What does the state collapse to?
The answer is that it collapses to the (normalized) linear combination found in the original state: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}}[a_1|\lambda_1\rangle+a_2|\lambda_2\rangle]$. The idea, in general, is that the state resulting from the collapse is what we get when we project the original state into the eigenspace associated with the measured eigenvalue and normalize the result.

@cookiecainsy OP: Let me stress this line in the answer here "Applying an operator to a quantum state does not correspond directly to taking a measurement of that state." That is really fundamental here: the action of an operator is not the mathematical correlate of the action of taking a measurement. This is a common mistake that leads to further mistakes. So take this to heart!

Actually I think I understand now. Is it correct to say that the usefulness of $
\hat{Q} \mid\psi_n\rangle= q \mid\psi_n\rangle$, lies in the fact that it tells you what value you can expect to observe, when a measurement made on a general state happens to land on a specific state. I was considering it as its own stand alone equation which was directly related to measurement, but I think I have a better understanding now.

The utility of operators extends beyond this. For example. If you have a state $|\psi\rangle$ and you wish to calculate the "expectation value of $\hat{Q}$" associated with the state (that is, the average of what value you expect to observe after a large number of measurements of copies of the same state), this value is given by $\langle\psi|\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle$.

But yes, if you have an eigenstate of $\hat{Q}$ (call it $|q\rangle$), you can extract the eigenvalue $q$ associated with that state by computing $\langle q|\hat{Q}|q\rangle=q\langle q|q\rangle=q$.

The time evolution of a quantum system is described by a path in the Hilbert space of states. This is a map $t\mapsto |\psi(t)\rangle$ that gives you a ket for each instant of time. When you have a position observable, $X$ you may form the wave function $\psi(t,x)=\langle x|\psi(t)\rangle$ by projecting onto one of its eigenstates, but the notion of "wave function collapse" applies more generally.
The basic idea is this, if $O$ is some generic observable and $|\lambda_i\rangle$ is its basis of eigenvectors (be it discrete or an improper continuous basis), we know that $$O|\lambda_i\rangle = \lambda_i|\lambda_i\rangle.$$
Considering the postulates of quantum mechanics, only on one of the states $|\lambda_i\rangle$ the observable $O$ has a well-defined value, and it is given by the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.
So suppose you have $|\psi(t)\rangle$. Now imagine that at some instant of time $t_0$ you decide to measure $O$. Note that this is not encoded in the evolution $|\psi(t)\rangle$ as one observer can decide to measure a physical quantity at any time, despite the dynamics of the system he is studying. In that scenario, once the measurement has been carried out, you have new information about the system, namely, now you know for sure the value of $O$, because you measured it.
Let's say the outcome of the measurement was $\lambda_i$. This means that immediately after $t_0$ the state of the system is no longer that predicted by $|\psi(t)\rangle$. You know it must be $|\lambda_i\rangle$, so that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}|\psi(t_0+\epsilon)\rangle=|\lambda_i\rangle$. This prescribes a new initial value condition for the time evolution, that gets updated from the new data.
The wave function collapse refers to this: after an observable has been measured, you have new information about the state of the system. This gives a new initial condition set at the time of the measurement, and changes its dynamics accordingly. There is nothing mysterious about it, though: the quantum state of a system is the maximum information we now about it. Once we make a measurement, we know new information about the system, so we necessarily must adapt our description accordingly

Your last paragraph is an interpretation (and not a fact)...
